# Declaration of object property using java OWL API

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

It's easy to create a declaration of OWL class i.e.

```
Declaration(Class(:ComponentIT))
```

using `java OWL API v5`:

```
OWLClass A = df.getOWLClass(IOR + "#ComponentIT");
OWLDeclarationAxiom da = df.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(A);
```

The question is
how to create a declaration of object property (an axiom for inserting into the OWLOntology object) using OWL API, i.e.

```
Declaration(ObjectProperty(:hasValue))
```

Comment: The same way as you did for classes...don't you use an IDE for programming? It should be suggested for `df.` -> `df.getOWLObjectProperty(...)`

Comment: Ok, the first step is:
OWLObjectProperty hasValue = df.getOWLObjectProperty(IOR + "#hasValue");

Then I have to get an axiom to use it as an argument of the OWLOntology.add() method.
How to get an axiom?

I'm using the mcedit & mvn.

Comment: The `OWLOntologyManager` provides the methods to add axioms to an `Ontology` object

Comment: And I don't understand your question regarding "get an axiom" - it is the same as you did for the class

Comment: Upps... You are right, thanks a lot. The getOWLDeclarationAxiom() method works for the properties the same way as for the classes. That's my fault. I tried to find something looking like getOWLObjectPropertyAxiom(). How to close the question here?

Comment: You can "close" the question by proving the answer and "accept" your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getOWLDeclarationAxiom() method works for the properties the same way as for the classes, i.e.

```
OWLObjectProperty hasValue = df.getOWLObjectProperty(IOR + "#hasValue");
OWLDeclarationAxiom d_hasValue = df.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(hasValue);
```

Comment: Take a look at the OWLAPI documentation page for examples and tutorials. https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Documentation